# How do I add an Apps Script function to a Google Sheets cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how to count the amount of times a group has clicked on a specific cell containing a cell.

I've gotten it to work with having a separate drawing next to it with the function attached to it, but I don't want to have a button needed for it.

```
function increment_t1() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F5').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F5').getValue() + 1);
}
```

And this then pastes the result into column F5 for how many times the button has been pressed.

Is there any way to attach the script to either a cell that contains a text that can be copied normally, or a checkbox that you can check next to it that resets to false every time it's clicked but counts the clicks?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `onSelectionChange` simple trigger together with a custom cell value (or another cell characteristic) to identify when certain part of your script should be executed. Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Increment the value of F5 every time a cell having webapplications
 * is selected
 */
function onSelectionChange(e){
  if(e.range.getValue() === 'webapplications'){
     const target =e.range.getSheet().getRange('F5');
     target.setValue(target.getValue() + 1);
  }
}
```

---

The only way to directly attach a script to a cell is by using it in a formula. This kind of scripts are called [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Unfortunately custom functions have limitations being of them that they can't use methods like `setValue`.

You might use [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) an [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). There are two types, simple and installable.  For this case, the trigger that is closer to what you are lookin is `onSelectionChange`. It's a simple trigger triggered when selecting one cell or multiple cells, it has an event object that including the `range` property that can be used to get information about the selected range like the cell value, but you could also add a note, the cell formatting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to attach the script to either a cell that contains a text that can be copied normally

Google Sheets does not have that functionality. Apps Script functions can only be directly attached to custom menu items, drawings, images and triggers.

> checkbox that you can check next to it that resets to false everytime it's clicked but counts the clicks?

That is fairly easy to do with the `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

See the [checkboxButtons_(e)](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/119054769?msgid=120084104) script for sample code.